# jQuery/CSS - Animating item selection

Tags: jquery, css

Imagine ul and li's, and an li is highlighted when selected, eg.

```
li.selected { background-color: Yellow; }
```

Is there a way to make the background animate/move to the selected item?

To better explain what I want, please see this link
http://jsfiddle.net/BVaV4/1/
Try clicking on the items, I want the background to animate just like that (but don't see the code I'm cheating there)

Is there an easy way to do this using jQuery and CSS? Surely someone has done it?

Comment: So what is your question? It seems the way you want it in the fiddle?

Comment: Agreed, what's happening here?

Comment: Its a good way to accomplish this animationg. However you can try animating `background-size` and `background-position` with an image as background.

Comment: Not that important, but in your example the z-indexes don't work. If you want them to, you need to use for example `position: relative` on the upper element, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BVaV4/15/

Comment: I have found you a solution, using jQuery UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you want to animate the "real" background, but that is not possible the way you want it. The "background" of a html element is directly behind the element. You can change it's position with `background-position:` but it will be clipped if it spans outside the element.

Every html element has a background, they are separate and you cannot animate between them the way you want. Not only a background cannot leave it's element, but jQuery animation is basically changing the properties of one element not "merging one" to an other.

So to achieve what you want you need a substitute. It seems you have already found it: you made a `<div>` under the given element, and instead of using it's background property, you use that `<div>`.

You may call it cheating, but what you have done is not that bad, you just need to wrap it up, because the screws are hanging out.

You can take the "real" background, and replace it with yours that behaves the way you intend it to.

You can make a jQuery plugin that

- can be applied to lists
- checks the background of the selected object (width, height, color, etc), you need to somehow mark the selected item (by giving it a .highlighted class for example).
- replaces the selected object's background with a div sharing similar properties
- when an other item is clicked, it moves the selection to the position of the clicked item and copy the other item's (width, height).

The goal would be to keep the html and css clean from anything that indicates that there will be a plugin used, and modify the html by javascript.

It might be possible that there is already a jQuery plugin out there providing the same effect, but most likely it is cheating the same way (although you would not have to write it again :) ).

---

**EDIT**:

After taking an other look at this, I found that jQuery UI already have an effect suitable for you:

The [`.effect()`](http://jqueryui.com/effect/) "transfer". You get a transfer element which slides and morphs from the source element to the target. You get to style it with a class.

I have wrapped up a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/BVaV4/22/

```
$(function () {
    $('li').click(function () {
        var $prev = $('li.selection'),
            $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.is('.selection')) {

            $prev.removeClass('selection');
            $prev.removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selection');

            $prev.effect('transfer', {
                to: '.selection', 
                className: "ui-effects-transfer"
            }, 500, function() {
                if ($this.hasClass('selection')) {
                    $this.addClass('selected');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Note that I have made a selected and selection class. This double classing prevents the magic falling apart if the user clicks too fast. If the user clicks too fast there is still a double background animated. If you make the animation faster it will be less visible.

It's possible that you could make the animation more consistent with [`jQuery.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/), by queueing all the animations and the class switching to the same queue, but I'm no animation magician, and I would need more time to figure out how (animating different elemets sequentially seems to be tricky).

Comment: +1 Very well described! Such jQuery plugin is exactly what I'm after!

Comment: Wow! You're the best SoonDead don't die!

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't want to leave my answer unfinished. And luckily my nickname is a pun, and not directly related to dying. :)

Answer (score 0):

For moving the background (without animation) you have to "select" only the last clicked item, and deselect all the others first.

```
$(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");       
    });
});
```

for a better effect you might refine a bit your styling

```
li.selected { background: #cdf; }
li:hover { color:#f96; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the first fiddle to show you how to do it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BVaV4/14/).

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $('.highlight').animate({'top': (18 + $(this).index() * 18)+'px'},function() {
    $('.highlight').css({'display': 'block'});
  });   
    });
 });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: question: "Is there a way to make the background animate/move to the selected item?"
The most powerful way to do it, is to create a background div of the li selected item's height. Then we display the background div and move it on the selected li element. 
And, this is what I have done in the link.

Comment: Although you have made slight corrections to the script presented in the question, it's still the same. The question is about finding a "less hacky" way.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use css sprites put in the background and have a timer animate it at 1/15 sec intervals.. but if the animation is complex the required bkg image could become quite big